# OpenJPA query validation error

Tags: jpql, openjpa

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT new com.acme.Rooms.RoomStatistics(r.floor.floorId ,SUM(r.roomCapacity), COUNT(DISTINCT r.roomType.roomTypeId), COUNT(r.roomId)) FROM Room r where r.disabled = 0 group by r.floor.floorId
```

My RoomStatistics constructor's signature is

```
(int, long, long, long)
```

I've noted the similar questions (where COUNT(AppleTree) should be replaced with COUNT(AppleTree.id)). But it looks a bit different.

I have the following error in markers view:

```
No constructors can be found that match the argument types.
```

What's the reason of this error? Is there a way I can debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've disabled JPA validation. It compiles good and runs as expected without the validation. Sort of workaround, but I was unable to find better solution.

[image: How to disable JPA validation]